One Wallet controlling multiple addresses?
is there a way to have multiple addresses all controlled by one wallet or keypair?  so essentially i could have funds spread across multiple addresses but send them all at once?

Did you think of using PDAs for that? https://solana.com/docs/core/pda

This is a bit of a vague question, so I'll give a few answers in the hopes that one of them addresses what you wanted.
One keypair only maps to one account / wallet, so it can only control those funds.
If you're using a seed phrase though, that can be interpreted in different ways using BIP-32 or BIP-44 hierarchical derivation. You can do this by adding some other part to your "path" when deriving the public address, ie:
solana airdrop 1 "prompt://?key=0/1"

More information at https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/wallets/paper#hierarchical-derivation
If you're talking about SPL Token accounts, one wallet / keypair can have as many token accounts as it wants. For example, you can repeatedly do:
solana-keygen new -o account.json
spl-token create-account <MINT> account.json

And there's still one more method, which is through "create-with-seed". This method isn't extremely well supported, but it is possible to use it, ie:
solana create-address-with-seed "some_string" <PROGRAM_ID>

More information at https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/usage#solana-create-address-with-seed
